# The system cannot find the path specified in anaconda command prompt

Tags: windows-10, anaconda

Whenever I open the Anaconda Prompt, I get the message above printed twice
[image: screenshot of my prompt]
How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

try executing `conda init` and restart the anaconda prompt. It should initialize the conda environment again.

Comment: where i write this "conda init"

Comment: conda init solved two problems for me. First was the one mentioned here and the second was PyCharm DLL Load Failed errors when running the python console and Jupyter.  Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Go to `Control Panel\System and Security\System\Advanced System Settings` then look for Environment Variables.

Your user variables should contain `Path=Path\to\Anaconda3\Scripts`.

You need to figure where your Anaconda3 folder is (i.e. the path to this folder). Mine was in `C:\Users\(User Name) \Anaconda3`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to go to the file location of the Anaconda Prompt (Figure 1), go to "Properties" of the Prompt (Figure 2) and change the links in "target" to the correct link to miniconda (in my case, the correct links are: "%windir%\System32\cmd.exe" /K ""C:\Program Files\miniconda3\Scripts\activate.bat" "C:\Program Files\miniconda3"")

(1) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHNuu.png)
(2) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89vo7.jpg)

Comment: This works for me after I change the location of the anaconda folder. Somehow the shortcut still points to an old path.

Answer (score 0):

Install anaconda with specified user not public. This option create the directed folder within the user name so just copy the directory into system - advanced - path and edit variables.