# Cannot find the path specified in anaconda command prompt

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, environment-variables

Hello guys I need your help, what happens is that I update w10 (although I did not want to), the problem is that when I enter Anaconda Prompt I get 2 messages:

```
The system can not find the path specified.
The system can not find the path specified.
```

[image: IMAGE OF MY ERROR]

I already tried what is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55057291/the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified-in-anaconda-command-prompt#:%7E:text=try%20executing%20conda%20init%20and,initialize%20the%20conda%20environment%20again.&text=Go%20to%20Control%20Panel%5CSystem,%5Cto%5CAnaconda3%5CScripts%20.). But it still doesn't work, the funny thing is that Anaconda PowerShell Prompt appeared and everything runs normal here.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can see all of your environments (including base env) with

```
conda info --envs
```

The paths displayed must be in your environment variables, which may have been altered with the windows update. I'd compare PATH in these environment variables and see if the output above is in there. If not, manually adding it should solve the issue.

Comment: Yes i can see the  environments ! I was thinking they were removed THANKS! ,but 
as you can see in my image it doesn't even start the base environment..